# Cosmos db order by clause doesn't work for exponential value

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

I am querying cosmos db and using order by clause on a "double" column. The order by clause is not working as expected.

I have a double column with below possible values. Notice that the first value below is the smallest.

```
 1)9.322415748667671E-5 2)0.4466757176768596 3)0.6817164130033916
```

If I order by desc, I expect to see this order

```
 1)0.6817164130033916 2)0.4466757176768596 3)9.322415748667671E-5
```

But instead I am seeing this order

```
1)9.322415748667671E-5 2)0.6817164130033916 3)0.4466757176768596
```

**Sample query**

```
SELECT *  FROM c
where c.col1 = "val1"
order by c.score desc
```

Can someone please suggest how can I fix this?

Comment: Can you try defining a composite index on this property? This is stored as numeric and not as string correct?

Comment: Correct it is stored as numeric. It's difficult to alter the schema for my current scenario. I would just prefer changing the query in code.

Comment: Defining a composite index does not change your schema.

Comment: When I tried to insert the data "9.322415748667671E-5" into my cosmosdb sqlapi, I found that whether I inserted it in portal or I used code inserted the item, I can both get the result "score": 0.00009322415748667671, so I can't generate data like yours.

Comment: Could you pls share your way of inserting data so that it can be stored like 9.322415748667671E-5

Comment: We are inserting it using ADF(Azure data factory pipeline)

Comment: @user911 Can you show me your screenshot of score `9.322415748667671E-5` in Cosmos DB? I think maybe you store score as string in Cosmos DB and the entity's type is numeric in your code which causes this problem .